# Как отменить запрос для сервера?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var ajax_request = "";

function go_ajax(){
    if(typeof ajax_request !== 'undefined'){
            ajax_request.abort();
        }

    ajax_request = $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/УРЛ_САЙТА',
        data: {par: params_},
        success: function(data) {
            //действия по success 
        }
    });
```

}

Как  отменить запрос для сервера .... ajax_request.abort() останавливает "прослушивание" для  клиента, сервер же пока не выполнит предыдущую задачи, остается занят

Comment: Проигнорировать.

Какой вопрос такой и ответ :)

Comment: вопрос, то чем не угодил. По-моему достаточно конкретный .....    
Если ли возможность отменить посланный ajax-запрос, после того,  как скрипт получил и начал обрабатывать данные, .... может быть так более понятно ....

Но скорее всего @forum3 прав

Comment: А чем не угодил ответ? :) Ну ок, я так понимаю сервер на PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если запрос ушел, то не остановите. Т.е если скрипт получил данные и начал что-то делать, то не остановите.

Попробуйте логику изменить таким образом, чтобы запрос делался только тогда, когда нужно.

Answer (score 1):

вот так можно:

```
if (ajax_request) {
    ajax_request.abort();
}
```

А что бы сервер не выполнял операцию дальше:
то [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)(false);

это для php. Для других не знаю, но уверен что что-либо подобное тоже есть.
Также стоит отметить что по умолчанию ignore_user_abort выставлен в false

Comment: Report a bug
 Примечания

PHP не сможет определить обрыв пользователем соединения пока не будет произведена попытка отправки информации клиенту. Простое использование выражения echo не гарантирует отправку информации, см. функцию flush().

 Скрипт  сделает работу все равно. Только логику менять

Comment: Могу ошибаться, может обойти можно как-то

Comment: по ссылке есть хороший пример, можете опробовать его ;) Example #1

я бы  написал что то вроде этого:

ignore_user_abort (false);

`for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
}

$f = fopen('/tmp/test', 'a+');
fwrite($f, "script has been finished at ".date('r')."\n");
fclose($f);
`

т.е если мы оборвём (нажмем esc в броузере) сразу же после начала загрузки (до 20сек) то в файлике запись появится не должна.

если запись не появится - то собственно всё работает правильно.

И я не совсем понял аналогию с echo